How can I render an ordered list as an HTML content inside a div?
I am trying to render an ordered list inside a div but it is coming out as plain text like "flour" instead of "1. flour".
Rendering other HTML contents works but the ordered list is not working for some reason. I mean I want to render it as the numbered list but now I am only getting plain text and not a numbered list


var renderMessage = "<ol><li>flour</li></ol>";
$('#message-content').html(renderMessage);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=message-content></div>




Hi, can you please demonstrate your code that you have up to now? where is the order list that you mentioned?

@Petros Hi yes sorry, it is actually inside msg.message so when i console log renderMessage it came out as flour. So like it is supposed to display as "1.Flour" right?

@yeonjunchoi msg.message is a string and console logging a string will display the string! You won't see an html in the console. You will need to display inject in the DOM in order to be displayed on the screen for it to work

Ok, I may have misunderstood the question - but it's hard to tell without a complete snippet that demonstrates the answer - as-is, the code provided will give errors and there's no association between renderMessage and openEnderContent.  Seting #messasge-content's .html() to the provided html string will output an ol - but using .text() will remove the ol content.

The 1.  is provided by css - as such, it is not included when you use .text().   Here's a reproduction on what it appears you're trying to do (without fixing the code in the question to make it [mcve]):  https://jsfiddle.net/upt9d5zL/  edit: updated to show difference between .html(str) and .html($("<div/>").html(str).text()): https://jsfiddle.net/upt9d5zL/1/

@fdomn-m Oh thank you for this! And i see then even if i try to render with this method $('#message-content').html(renderMessage); or even use append, it still doesn't work

Do you have an [tag:css]?  Can you [edit] the question to provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the issue?

I've converted your code to a runnable snippet, including adding the missing " as you've mentioned this is a string in the comments.   Please [edit] the question so that it demonstrates the issue (I suspect you have some css that hides the ol numbering).

Oh @fdomn-m thank you for this! It seems to be working after the string "". I think this question can be closed now. Thanks a bunch!

Thanks for the feedback.  Looks like it might just have been a syntax error when building the string - I recommend you close your question if/when you can.

yes I will do it @fdomn-m
